# Find a function that satisfies this property

Tags: functions

I should find at least one function that satisfies this property for every $x \in \mathbb R $ 
$$   f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0  & \text{if $x \ge 0$} \\
1 & \text{if $x \lt 0$ }
\end{cases} $$
**My try:**
$$ f(x)= -\frac {x}{2\lvert x \rvert}+\frac 12 $$
But it doesn't satisfy the condition that $x$ could be zero. 
So, can you help me with that ?

Answer (score 6):

$$   f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0  & \text{if $x \ge 0$} \\
1 & \text{if $x \lt 0$ }
\end{cases} $$

**Is** a function. It is defined for every $x\in\mathbb R$.

---

One way of writing it "without cases" is to say that $f(x)=\chi_{(-\infty, 0)}(x)$, because for any set $A\subseteq \mathbb R$, the ["characteristic" or "indicator" function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $A$ is defined as being $1$ on $A$ and $0$ everywhere else.

Comment: I wanted a general notation

Comment: Certainly the most straightforward solution :)

Comment: @CarwLucas what does "general notation" mean?

Comment: A function that doesn't use cases

Comment: @CarwLucas But... how do you define $|x|$?

Comment: $|x|$ is a common function. I wanted to use common functions to generalize the function I stated without using cases. Sorry if the question was unclear.

Comment: Umm, don't you mean $\chi_{(-\infty,0)}$?

Comment: @ForgotALot Yeah, thanks.